# setState Is that immuteable or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to ask you is that immuteable or not ?

```
  // Select all product options that you selected for each product we store it in an array
  const [selectedProductOptions, setSelectedProductOptions] = useState<ISizeAndColors[] | []>([]);

    findObj && setSelectedProductOptions(prev => {
      return prev.map((el => {
        if(el.product_id === currentProductID) {
          return {
            ...el,
            color,
            size,
            amount
          }
        } else {
          return {
            ...el
          }
        }
      }))
```

If not what I am doing then wrong ?

Comment: That code doesn't mutate anything, does it do what you want?

Comment: yes I have a color in a array with the product id, if the color changes then I set a new color where the product id is the same, it works but how can I write this to immuteable ?

Comment: This is immutable. Where would the mutation be if it wasn't? Are you having a real problem in your code or just speculating/quizzing us? I suggest a [mcve] if you are having a problem, along with a detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve and where/how the code is failing. Thanks.

Comment: I think the type should be just <ISizeAndColors [ ]>

Comment: Regarding the rest of the code it seems correct to me (although it's incomplete so the error could be elsewhere).